# Qt C++ border icon

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I create new application and remove title bar with close, maximize and minimize buttons (just set windowFlags to `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint`). I created my own buttons. Now I must search icons for removed buttons, but I can't find them (close, minimize, maximize).

Question: Can I use Windows 7 icons? Doesn't it violate the license?

Answer (score 4):

You could use Qt's QStyle to obtain the icons that Qt uses to draw its own title bars and such:

```
QStyle* style = QApplication::style();
QIcon icon = style->standardIcon( QStyle::SP_TitleBarCloseButton );
```

Have a look at the [`QStyle::StandartPixmap` enum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum) for a list of Qt's standard icons that are available.

Comment: thanks, it works. But this icons looks like Windows XP style. Can I get Windows 7 icon?

Comment: You can enumerate the available styles by using QStyleFactory::keys(). I'm pretty sure the Windows 7 styles is only available if you're running the application on Windows 7, unfortunately.

Comment: results of QStyleFactory::keys() is: 

Windows,
WindowsXP,
WindowsVista,
Motif,
CDE,
Plastique,
Cleanlooks.

I setup application style to each one of this style types, style was changed, but icon (close button) looks like default Windows7 button (color isn't red, without beautiful lights). My OS is Windows 7, with default theme.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing the buttons as bitmap images or even embedded in your application would most likely be a violation of Windows' EULA.

However, if your app runs on Windows, you don't need to distribute them. Just find where the Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons are stored in Windows 7 (probably some DLL in the system folder), then when you app runs, use these icons directly (I believe QIcon can load them). That way, there's no copyright violation.